# One who reads newspapers

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking to write a Java interface similar to Observer/Observable but with Newspaper/*insert_word_here*. I'd like the word to not be something simple like *reader*, but has some sort of reference to what the reader is reading.

If someone has other suggestions of an item that is read/viewed/etc and a corresponding noun-ified verb that goes alongside while referencing the item type I would also like to see that.

*Meta - I wanted to add a tag 'word-pair' for the alternative second half but I couldn't due to low reputation. If anyone wants to add it, or if they feel like it should be a separate question, feel free to comment.*

Comment: I don't know what the Java interface "Observer/Observable" is; but *observable* is an adjective, not a nounified verb. What is it that you are asking for?

Comment: I meant 'observer' as the nounified verb (not sure what the proper term is), and observable is the newspaper.

Comment: Agent noun; but then *newspaper* is not one of those.

Comment: The agent noun is the person acting on the object. In the case of the Observable, the Observable is in fact an adjective, but it could be read as making the class observable. "The *observable* messageboard was observed by the *observer*."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's code, then what's wrong with `NewspaperReader`?  Better to have a clunky, explicit name than something pretty but less informative.

(`NewsReader` would is easier to say, but means something else.)

Comment: Ah, you're very right. Clarity over attractiveness is where I should be headed.

Answer (score 0):

In my apps I refer to these things as **Paper Edition (reader).**  Your application or site could still be viewed as part of the newspaper.